# The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character when working with X509Certificate certificate

Tags: c#, wcf, encryption, soap, base64

I get the private key from a X509Certificate but when I call the Convert.FromBase64String method I get an error that says:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64
>   character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character
>   among the padding characters.

Here is the encrypted key

> j0ZKFBmTz3Kj0cQ82rq63MYAR+0=c+WfKnOxqmDVC6uhsFPQjAVcjsAcD5+QkpoGiNN3UcGmPIf6V/JiahTY+6ZXir+Mnw0d2Fe805vJ3i8p2itsbaPWiWKU56WeI6b5odIm/HfKTWibM1JYQ9MMAKv2nym0stjyeSieQwwR2vBXvwY2e0hNb88qy22/cOKpjATKgM9tg755hdl5Po24ARFwjnTj12jFANepzmpDcEvlF7LPmN5s2ZzDGC9h3KVJQ8WhB53yIDeQLXdmB7DtnIwF0ocw5idSkOGSMZTdAumIUzerFvQ1Qw02KcPb5nyqxZkvc1hXiqVFqe6SBRRuokFlm7VwfaT2hbPl+GX02LSZXKn3qg==

Here is my code

```
var encryptedKey = doc.GetElementsByTagName("e:EncryptedKey")[0].InnerText;
var cipherText = doc.GetElementsByTagName("e:CipherValue")[1].InnerText;
var cipher = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

 var clientCert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\certificates\xxxxx.pfx", "xxxxxx");
 var rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)clientCert.PrivateKey;
 byte[] key = rsa.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedKey), false);
```

xml:

```
<s:Envelope 
    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
    xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <VsDebuggerCausalityData 
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPo4tYpt6X40FEk+VSAe5mc8MAAAAAP497cBuXfk+uFIOY80O0iuLtIW56q7hLktgVYPhbnHMACQAA
        </VsDebuggerCausalityData>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" 
            xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-10490fb0-8ee0-4a4c-a8db-77242c9a3b7f-2" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">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</o:BinarySecurityToken>
            <e:EncryptedKey Id="_0" 
                xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" 
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" />
                </e:EncryptionMethod>
                <KeyInfo 
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <o:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509SubjectKeyIdentifier" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">j0ZKFBmTz3Kj0cQ82rq63MYAR+0=</o:KeyIdentifier>
                    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
                <e:CipherData>
                    <e:CipherValue>ANCElFZ5v/nkh7olNmxSN3tugOi0WakX2loTeKAc6xg97KgUGsCpOcMQIEBeij9YUUtW7iciBqfNX9dd4FYWVap4MI3MVz0KAdfT8m5aLIlcrfvdSZ2/OtoeiriNn6s51yhbcVGBRw9kL9suAYk5sREdTEOd9kI2BUj1d5jmLMy+iAvoSioGrVXPCScJPOPiWKf5mDyx59bAf6W7sVkdqXUpiw1ROxGeqYA4yXL2KBcP5gJ59AZ7LedQcg8mRD6nl+lg/yp0gVdkkEtzN92paw/mLOBeXk5NXiltMvudNJKYkSp6ZfhXy2wIUR7LYR57nUB4mNRaIOC28QAASCF7nQ==</e:CipherValue>
                </e:CipherData>
                <e:ReferenceList>
                    <e:DataReference URI="#_2" />
                </e:ReferenceList>
            </e:EncryptedKey>
            <Signature 
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
                    <Reference URI="#_1">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <DigestValue>akiomlPdi6j1h6r9NDqmh9G1GD0=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>LIjqWD/BXsoA0XNR7hvmcTkDIdUvgy2BGDT2Xwz4OSerUMAxMO2wpfScIA9ISzxt0mw6lw8KKmRzecifCC3CMYqCig3Yu2u/VZmeyA55oeKHq8GTE4Tn9IFq0/053GCODfJOlrKYM/b1Xj//x2YvE/opKw5l3V3lsVvpXfmkci3jNUM4E0oixlQVIKjcKB68L5b6+9PS97t9Yj+dGc4Z2/aCS+I2dVMCcH62FeB/P3XwelZoy5LN2GM9sVWJQ+bnUmbpRlaY5INPnvFbZ0yfD9umxB4jS48smsPvMDxZzx7dr1SdcPA3Rbsrx495Y9r1KEFoXP6vuKf18EEhgGWpXQ==</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#uuid-10490fb0-8ee0-4a4c-a8db-77242c9a3b7f-2" />
                    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body u:Id="_1">
        <e:EncryptedData Id="_2" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" 
            xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc" />
            <e:CipherData>
                <e:CipherValue>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</e:CipherValue>
            </e:CipherData>
        </e:EncryptedData>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: See `=` in  `....YAR+0=c+WfKnOxq.......`. It can not be in a base64 encoded string (Except at the end).

Comment: Which makes it possible this is 2 base64 strings joined together. We (you) need a look at the code that fills "e:EncryptedKey". And maybe the XML.

Comment: I suspect you are calling `InnerText` on something that has more elements as children and `InnerText` is concatenating their text values.

Comment: @HenkHolterman :) You are right. 20 bytes  + 256 bytes

Comment: @everyone.  I think you guys are right.  I'm looking at the xml and I believe that is what is happening.  So what should I do now?

Comment: Edit your question and post the XML (note the `{}` button in the editor)

Comment: @Eser - yes, but that leaves some questions. 20 bytes is a strange value for an IV.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I added the xml

Comment: @HenkHolterman sha1 hash is 160 bit. it can be related to this

Comment: @esr - yes, but it's more complicated than I expected. There are 2 `<e:CipherValue>`

Comment: @MindGame encrypted key itself is in `CipherValue` element (I mean one under `EncryptedKey`, not one in body), not in `EncryptedKey` which contains quite some more information (such as what algotihms being used, encrypted with which key, and so on).

Comment: @MindGame - the sane thing here would be to use the appropriate libraries. Looks like you are going DIY on soap security.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yeah.  For some reason WCF is not decrypting my message.  So I'm trying to do it manually.  Do you know which libraries I should be using?

Comment: @Evk  How do you know that is the encrypted key?  I'm following a post by this guy http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2014/06/emedny-web-services-in-net-guest-post.html where he decrypts the soap response manually.

Comment: Well it's not just some random xml, it follows certain specification. And that specification states what is what there. Body of the message is encrypted with symmetric algorithm key (random generated just for this). That encrypted data is under `EncryptedData > CipherData > CipherValue` in body. Symmetric key itself is encrypted with assymetric algorithm key (private key of your certificate). That encrypted key is stored under `EncryptedKey  > CipherData > CipherValue`. So you need first to decrypt a key (using pk of your certificate), and then decrypt message body with that key.

Comment: And if you want to avoid all that - try to use `SignedXml` built-in class. I'm certainly used it many times to verify signatures, but I believe it can decrypt as well.

Comment: Re libraries, I was thinking WCF. And SignedXml as second. That " For some reason WCF is not ..." means some part is wrong, not so sure you are solving that this way.

Comment: I looked at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-decrypt-xml-elements-with-x-509-certificates.  But I don't see example of where the certifciate is being used.  I got a bit confused with the SignedXml.

Comment: Yes, `EncryptedXml` is the way to go (`SignedXml` uses it as `SignedXml.EncryptedXml` property, but since you don't care about signature - you can just use `EncryptedXml` directly. As for how to use cert - as far as I know - it will search matching cert in your certificate store (I think in "My" of current user or machine). It will use subject specified in key info for that. So if you have correct certificate in store - just do `var en = new EncryptedXml(yourDoc); en.DecryptDocument()`

Comment: This drifted a long way from a simpel base64 question... Leave this one stand  and ask again, this time about your actual problem.

Comment: Thanks for all your guys help. I'm getting another error now.  But I created a new ticket for this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49722382/decrypt-soap-message